# How to get AutocompletePredictionBuffer from AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse in xamarin android

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Google Places autocomplete for my xamarin.android application. I am calling "GetAutocompletePredictions". On "OnComplete(Task task)" method i am getting task where i am getting "AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse" but now i am unable to get AutocompletePredictionBuffer from AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Location.Places;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Gms.Tasks;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Java.Lang;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GooglePlacesAndroidNative
{
  [Activity(Label = "GooglePlacesAndroidNative", MainLauncher = 
   true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity, IOnCompleteListener, 
                                                 IOnSuccessListener
{
    GeoDataClient getGeoDataClient;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new 
        LatLng(38.46572222050097, -107.75668023304138), new 
        LatLng(39.913037779499035, -105.88929176695862));

        getGeoDataClient = 
         PlacesClass.GetGeoDataClient(Android.App.Application.Context, 
          null);

        Android.Gms.Tasks.Task result = 
         getGeoDataClient.GetAutocompletePredictions("pune", bounds, 
          null);

        result.AddOnCompleteListener(this);

        result.AddOnSuccessListener(this);

    }

    public void OnComplete(Task task)
    {
        AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse test = (AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse)task.Result;
    }


    public void OnSuccess(Object result)
    {
        AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse test = (AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse)result;
    }
}
}
```

My question is "getGeoDataClient.GetAutocompletePredictions("pune", bounds, null)" function is returning Android.Gms.Tasks.Task which is "AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse". In Java android "AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse" class has a functions like "get(int)", "getCount()" but in xamarin.android same function  doesn't have all these functions from which i can get Placess info. Instead "AutocompletePredictionBuffer" has all these functions in xamarin.android. Now my question is when i get api response in OnComplete(Task) i am getting "AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse", from this class object how can i get all the info about PLacess or atleast how can i get "AutocompletePredictionBuffer" object.

Comment: Show us the full activity please

Comment: @G.hakim can u give me the solutions?

Comment: Sushi has answered your question below please check that

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin has Extension-based helpers and thus you can use C# style async/await with those Android.Gms.Tasks.Tasks via `GetAutocompletePredictionsAsync`

```
var bufferResponse = await getGeoDataClient.GetAutocompletePredictionsAsync("pune", bounds, null);
```

Or using Xamarin's Android.Gms.Extensions:

```
var result = await TasksExtensions.AsAsync<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse>(getGeoDataClient.GetAutocompletePredictions("pune", bounds, null));
```

Comment: Thanx @SushilHangover, but how can i get Places info from "AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse" object

Comment: I have edited my question little bit, hope u will get more clarity now.